# PySpark: Converting Spark Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe [alternative for .toPandas()]

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a huge spark data frame with many columns (PySpark). [number of columns around 100 and number of rows more than 5000000]. I want to convert this data frame into Pandas data frame.
However, by df.toPandas() is not efficient, since it takes lots of time.

Any help on this please?